# Comaximal ideals in ring of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X $ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and $C (X) $ the ring of real continuous functions over $X $. Let $I $and $J $ be two comaximal ideals of $C (X) $, that is,  $I+J=C (X) $. How can we construct an idempotent function $f\in C (X) $( that is, $ff=f^2=f $) such that $I+<f>=C (X) $ and $ J+< 1-f  > =C (X) $, where $< f  > $ is the ideal generated by $f $.( Probably $f\not\in I $)

Comment: Well, a good first step would be to show that $X$ cannot be connected unless one of $I$ or $J$ is all of $C(X)$. Indeed, if neither $I$ nor $J$ is the full space then the conclusion will involve locating a non-trivial idempotent $f$. Any such idempotent must take values in $\{0,1\}$ and can therefore be written as an indicator function of some subset $A\subset X$. Then $A$ must be a non-trivial clopen set in order for $f=1_A$ to be continuous and non-constant, so $X$ must be disconnected.